# Program that adds unique words from text file to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program that reads a text file with multiple lines of text and adds unique words to an ArrayList. Then, I need to sort this ArrayList and print it.
My input is:

> Hello my
>   my name is
>   Java.

I originally thought my problem was that once the Scanner hit a word that is already in the ArrayList, it stopped. But, after changing my input, I have no idea what my problem is anymore.
My output is now:

> There are 2 unique word(s)
>   These words are:
>   is
>   my

I need my output to be:

> There are 5 unique word(s)
>   These words are:
>   Hello
>   Java
>   is
>   my
>   name

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Indexer
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("File.txt"));
      fileScanner.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
      ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
      while (fileScanner.hasNext())
      { 
         if (!words.contains(fileScanner.next()) && (fileScanner.hasNext()))
         {
           words.add(fileScanner.next());
         }
      }
      Collections.sort(words);
      System.out.println("There are " +  words.size() + " unique word(s)");
      System.out.println("These words are:");
      for (Iterator<String> it = words.iterator(); it.hasNext();) 
      {
          String f = it.next();
          System.out.println(f);
      }
      fileScanner.close();
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use a `Set`, "A collection that contains no duplicate elements."

Comment: why not split the string on a " " space and a new line?

Comment: @SuncoastOwner - What's wrong with the way the OP is currently doing it?  Your suggestion will make to program more complicated, not less.

Comment: Using a Set would've probably been more simple. I didn't realize that's what a Set was. We're learning about Collections and Basic Data Structures in school now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `next()` repeatedly, more than it should be used. Collect the value of the `next()` call in a variable and use that instead. E.g.

```
while (fileScanner.hasNext())
    {
        String nextWord = fileScanner.next();
        if (!words.contains(nextWord))
        {
            words.add(nextWord);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's what my problem was. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For a start don't call scanner.next() twice inside the loop

```
  ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (fileScanner.hasNext())
  { 
     String word = fileScanner.next();
     if (!words.contains(word))
     {
       words.add(word);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
     if (!words.contains(fileScanner.next()) && (fileScanner.hasNext()))
     {
       words.add(fileScanner.next());
     }
```

Each call to `next()` reads another word.  So in the above code you are reading and testing one word, then reading and adding the next one.  This is NOT correct.  You don't want to throw away words ...

Hint: use a local variable to hold the word you have just read ...

Comment: That's what my problem was. Thanks for the help!