# Adding unique words to ArrayList from a text file [.contains()/for/foreach]

Tags: java, arraylist

I am scanning a text file and adding the words to an **ArrayList** called `uniqueWordList`. The ArrayList should contain a word only once (no duplicate). Here are my attempts:

Edit: *I am supposed to get 990 words*.

### Using foreach:

```
while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
    nextWord = fileScanner.next();
    if(!nextWord.isEmpty()) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (String i : uniqueWordList) {
            if (nextWord.equalsIgnoreCase(i)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            uniqueWordList.add(nextWord);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: I get 933 words.

### Using contains():

```
while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
    nextWord = fileScanner.next();
    if(!nextWord.isEmpty()) {
        if(!uniqueWordList.contains(nextWord)) {
            uniqueWordList.add(nextWord);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: I get 989 words. Probably because I can't do a case-insensitive search. I've looked for it and found that case-insensitive search doesn't exist for `.contains()`.

I've done it myself even before I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453636/program-that-adds-unique-words-from-text-file-to-an-arraylist), but it didn't solve my problem. I'm still getting one less word.

What am I doing wrong?


P.S: *Any other built-in Java classes/packages such as List, Map, HashMap etc are not allowed.*
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean `List` not allowed while you're definitely using it?

Comment: That's what my homework says. I'm gonna update it.

Comment: Your issue does not seem to be reproducible, please check [this online demo](https://ideone.com/lOFvKa)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was missing a `!`. However, I'm supposed to get 990 words. Using `contains()` I get 989, and after fixing it now, I'm getting 933. Why is that? Should it not do the same whether I use `.contains()` or `for (i : list)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check all of the words in the `ArrayList` (not just the first one).

```
for (String i : uniqueWordList) {
    if (!nextWord.equalsIgnoreCase(i)) {
        uniqueWordList.add(currentWord);
        break;
    }
}
```

Should be something like

```
boolean found = false;
for (String i : uniqueWordList) {
    if (nextWord.equalsIgnoreCase(i)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) { // Now we have checked all of the words, or the word was found.
    uniqueWordList.add(nextWord); // What was currentWord anyway?
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. currentWord is actually nextWord.

Comment: It's adding the first word of the file twice. Nothing else.

Comment: Remove `if (arrElCount > 0) {` and the `else`.

Comment: Inside my `if(!nextWord.isEmpty()) { }` I have nothing but your answer. Still getting only the first word twice.

Comment: Edit your question, include enough code to reproduce the current issue.

Comment: Edited the first part.

Comment: @randomdude That is not enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, here *distinct* and *unique* words should be distinguished more clearly.

The existing code selects only *distinct* values - that is, if a duplicate value is found it is not included in the result list:

```
[aaa, bbb, ccc, AAA, Aaa, Bbb, DDD] -> [aaa, bbb, ccc, DDD]
```

However, *unique* may refer only to the words which occur *exactly* one time in the input file / stream, that is, `aaa` and `bbb` should not be counted as *unique*.

Let's use two separate lists:

```java
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner("aaa bbb ccc AAA Aaa Bbb DDD");
List<String> uniqueWordList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> distinctWordList = new ArrayList<>();
readNext:
while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
    String nextWord = fileScanner.next();
    
    for (String i : distinctWordList) {
        if (nextWord.equalsIgnoreCase(i)) { // non-distinct word found
            for (String unique : uniqueWordList) {
                if (unique.equalsIgnoreCase(nextWord)) {
                    uniqueWordList.remove(unique); // renove from unique list too
                    break;
                }
            }
            continue readNext;
        }
    }
    distinctWordList.add(nextWord);
    uniqueWordList.add(nextWord);
}
System.out.println("distinct: " + distinctWordList);
System.out.println("unique: " + uniqueWordList);
```

Output:

```
distinct: [aaa, bbb, ccc, DDD]
unique: [ccc, DDD]
```

*Note:* The code above uses `continue label` instead of setting and checking boolean flag `found`

---

`contains` may be used if the `distinctWordList` is allowed to contain normaized words (only upper or only lower case):

```java
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner("aaa bbb ccc AAA Aaa Bbb DDD");
List<String> uniqueWordList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> distinctWordList = new ArrayList<>();

while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
    String nextWord = fileScanner.next();
    String lower = nextWord.toLowerCase();
    
    if (!distinctWordList.contains(lower)) {
        distinctWordList.add(lower);  // distinct stores word in lower case to use contains
        uniqueWordList.add(nextWord); // unique stores original word
    } else {
        for (String unique : uniqueWordList) {
            if (unique.equalsIgnoreCase(nextWord)) {
                uniqueWordList.remove(unique);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("distinct: " + distinctWordList);
System.out.println("unique: " + uniqueWordList);
```

Output

```
distinct: [aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd]
unique: [ccc, DDD]
```